# C++ vector and segmentation faults

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, binary-tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a simple mathematical parser. Something that just reads `number = 1 + 2;`

I have a vector containing these tokens. They store a type and string value of the character. I am trying to step through the vector to build an AST of these tokens, and I keep getting segmentation faults, even when I am under the impression my code should prevent this from happening.

Here is the bit of code that builds the AST:

```
struct ASTGen
{
    const vector<Token>            &Tokens;
    unsigned int                   size,
                                   pointer;

    ASTGen(const vector<Token> &t) : Tokens(t), pointer(0) 
    {
        size = Tokens.size() - 1;
    }

    unsigned int next()
    {
        return pointer + 1;
    }

    Node* Statement()
    {
        if(next() <= size)
        {
            switch(Tokens[next()].type)
            {
                case EQUALS
                :
                    Node* n = Assignment_Expr();
                    return n;
            }
        }

        advance();
    }

    void advance()
    {
        if(next() <= size) ++pointer;
    }

    Node* Assignment_Expr()
    {
        Node* lnode = new Node(Tokens[pointer], NULL, NULL);
        advance();
        Node* n = new Node(Tokens[pointer], lnode, Expression());
        return n;
    }

    Node* Expression()
    {
        if(next() <= size)
        {                        
            advance();
            if(Tokens[next()].type == SEMICOLON)
            {
                Node* n = new Node(Tokens[pointer], NULL, NULL);
                return n;
            }

            if(Tokens[next()].type == PLUS)
            {
                Node* lnode = new Node(Tokens[pointer], NULL, NULL);
                advance();
                Node* n = new Node(Tokens[pointer], lnode, Expression());
                return n;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`...`

```
ASTGen AST(Tokens);
Node* Tree = AST.Statement();
cout << Tree->Right->Data.svalue << endl;
```

I can access `Tree->Data.svalue` and get the `=` Node's token info, so I know that node is getting spawned, and I can also get `Tree->Left->Data.svalue` and get the variable to the left of the `=`

I have re-written it many times trying out different methods for stepping through the vector, but I always get a segmentation fault when I try to access the `=` right node (which should be the `+` node)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's plenty more code that we haven't seen, so I can't tell you precisely what's going on, but I see a few things that are reasons for concern. One is that the Statement() method doesn't always return a value. If the first `if` test doesn't pass, then we call `advance()` and fall off the bottom of the routine without an explicit return. The caller will try to get the return value of the function but it'll get garbage. This could lead to all sorts of problems, including things like double `free()` calls, etc, which can easily cause segfaults.

`Expression()` has the same problem.

Comment: His `Expression()` function also has code paths that don't return a value.

Comment: I do realize this, but for right now I was not concerned as this should properly work against `number = 1 + 2;` , or atleast, that was the hope. Once I can get this test case resolved, I will finish up the other control paths.

Comment: @Headspin: Turn up the warning level on your compiler. You may have similar questionable things in other places.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Blastfurnace. I compiled with `-Wall` and I was able to see the errors. And thank you Ernest. Because of the warning level turned up I was able to see that I was reaching the end of my control path without a return type. I'll make sure not to assume these things in the future.